# MySQL Select From Map fields

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL 2 Table like this

**Table_1**
[image: Table_1]

**Table_2**
[image: Table_2]

And i want result table like this

**Result Table**

[image: Result_Table]

So, I put this query

```
SELECT A.TAG,B.VALUE
FROM TABLE_1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B
On A.CODE=B.CODE;
```

And can i create automatic map field when i want this result table i just call

```
SELECT TAG,VALUE FROM MAP_TABLE WHERE TAG IN('ASSX','ASPS','AAPP');
```

Comment: need to have a join condition.. after that, you can put it in a view called map_table. [ join condition syntax is on key=key not where key=key ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try nested selects?

```
SELECT tag ,value FROM
(   SELECT A.TAG as tag ,B.VALUE as value
    FROM TABLE_1 A
    LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B
    On A.CODE=B.CODE;)
 WHERE tag IN('ASSX','ASPS','AAPP');
```

**Other solution**: Creating new table from query.

```
create table map_table(
tag varchar(255),
value int);
```

And then filling this table with your needed values:

```
INSERT INTO map_table
(SELECT A.TAG as tag ,B.VALUE as value
FROM TABLE_1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B
On A.CODE=B.CODE;)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Grael. Yes, i try this. And i have question, can i do this in other way.

Comment: You can create new table in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You look like trying to use sub-query like this:

```
SELECT tag, value
FROM (SELECT a.tag, b.value
      FROM table_1 a
      LEFT JOIN table_2 b On a.code = b.code)
WHERE tag IN('ASSX','ASPS','AAPP');
```

However, you can simply add the condition to your first query:

```
SELECT a.tag, b.value
FROM table_1 a
LEFT JOIN table_2 b On a.code = b.code
WHERE a.tag IN('ASSX','ASPS','AAPP');
```